# How to avoid normal users from accessing others likewise home folder?

Tags: 12.04, users, home-directory, active-directory, likewise

How can I avoid normal users from accessing other users home folders?

All the users login via AD a/c but here in Ubuntu 12.04 anyone can easily access other users home folder including Administrator directory how am I able to avoid this happening?

Answer (score 0):

By default i think that only the creator of a file or folder can access it, but in your case it seems to be different.

You could change the permissions for your home folders by opening a root file manager by

```
gksudo nautillus
```

and then right click on the respective home folders, navigate to the permissions tab and change them as you like.

there would be an option like-

'allow other users to view and edit the files'

uncheck it to prevent other users to access each other's files.